# How do I use PowerShell with Gitlab CI in Gitlab Pages?

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pages

How do I use PowerShell commands/scripts with Gitlab CI in a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file which is used to deploy to gitlab pages?

I am trying to execute the `build.ps1` file from `.gitlab-ci.yml`, but when it reaches the `build.ps1` line, it gives an error saying
**/bin/bash: line 5: .build.ps1: command not found**

I am trying to use the PowerShell script to convert a file in my repo and have the converted file deployed to gitlab pages using `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Here is my code:

**.gitlab.yml**

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - .\build.ps1
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: I have used this and it worked without any issue. [Powershell GitLab-part3](http://www.powershell.amsterdam/2015/12/04/powershell-and-gitlab-ci-part-3/). You can go through all the parts to have a complete understanding on this.

Comment: I have been through the 5 tutorials on their website, but it requires having to install the Windows runner on your own machine and considerable setup before it would probably work. Why do you have to install the runner on your own machine for it to work. Previously when i used gitlab ci with .gitlab-ci.yml I did not have to install any application on my own machine. The static website created using different static generator on https://gitlab.com/pages/ is an example of that as you could just fork the repo to have your own website hosted using gitlab pages

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have been able to figure out a solution to my own question.

**Solution**

To Run PowerShell Command/Script from a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file on a **gitlab.com** using the Gitlab CI, you need to make sure that the contents of your .gitlab-ci.yml file is as shown below.

Note: The `.gitlab-ci.yml` below works without having to install a Gitlab Runner on your own machine and has been tested on the http://gitlab.com website.

```
image: philippheuer/docker-gitlab-powershell

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  # run PowerShell Script
  - powershell -File build.ps1
  # run PowerShell Command
  - powershell -Command "Get-Date"
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Answer (score 6):

The docker image `philippheuer/docker-gitlab-powershell` is outdated. The source on Github was also deleted.

I use in my `gitlab-ci.yml` the following image `mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest` more Informations available [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-powershell)

```
scriptjob:
  stage: script
  image: 
    name: "mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest"
  script:
    - pwsh ./myscript.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having trouble launching grunt within their gitlab CI/CD via a powershell file, add this line to the top of your file:

```
$env:path += ";" + (Get-Item "Env:AppData").Value + "\npm"
```