# How to convert powershell exe calls to YAML for git CI/CD

Tags: powershell, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, devops

I am having difficulty understanding the syntax of yaml. I want to convert the below power shell commands for restoring nuget packages and building visual studio solution to yaml. I am not able to get it correct, pls help.

**PowerShell Commnds:**

```
$ProjectPath = "e:\GitExperiment\SGen"
Set-Location $ProjectPath
$MSBuildPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
$NugetExePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\nuget.exe"
& $NugetExePath restore $ProjectPath\SGen.sln
& $MSBuildPath\MSBuild.exe $ProjectPath\SGen.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFramework=v4.7.2  /p:SkipPostSharp=True /p:RunCodeAnalysis=False
```

**YAML**

```
stages:
    - BUILD
    - UNITTEST
    - DEPLOY
BUILD_RestoreNugetPackages:
    script:
        - '$ProjectPath = e:\GitExperiment\SGen"'
        - 'Set-Location $ProjectPath'
        - '$MSBuildPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"'
        - '$NugetExePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\nuget.exe"'
        -  '"$NugetExePath restore $ProjectPath\SGen.sln"'
    stage: BUILD
    tags:
        - ci
BUILD_SolutionBuild:
    script:
        - "& $MSBuildPath $ProjectPath\\SGen.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFramework=v4.7.2  /p:SkipPostSharp=True /p:RunCodeAnalysis=False"
    stage: BUILD
    tags:
        - ci
```

I tried using quotes and double quotes and escaping characters in yaml. But couldn't get the commands right.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

While a [gitlab-ci runner does support Powershell](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/#powershell), I would rather:

- put those commands in a script (versioned with the rest of the sources)
- call that script from your YAML directives

  ```
  powershell -noprofile -noninteractive -executionpolicy Bypass -file my-script.ps1
  ```

That way, you don't have to deal with trying to escape any special characters.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As u suggested I created three ps1 files with the commands to restore nuget, build and deploy. Placed them in the same folder on git as that of the yml file. But I get the below error.

Comment: $ powershell -noprofile -noninteractive -executionpolicy Bypass -command RestoreNuget.ps1
RestoreNuget.ps1 : The term 'RestoreNuget.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ RestoreNuget.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (RestoreNuget.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @manjuv Sorry, I have edited my answer: this should be `-file`, not `-command` (see https://gist.github.com/ishu3101/0bdb1ec60a1371b07414bd0ab28f4227 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429681/6309 as an example)